# No fill from ad server. W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3

Tags: android, admob

Hello guys I am using Admob with my android app to display Banner ads in my app.
the problem is that ads are not displayed when I use the unit id that I have created in my admob console, but when when I use the test ad unit id , it works fine.
I have created the admob app more than 3 hours ago,but any ads are displayed yet.
I read a lot of answers about this issue but nothing helpt me.
do you have any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1):

you have just to wait, it took me a long time to start displaying ads